# Comparing two similar lists in excel on mac to find duplicates

Tags: macos, microsoft-excel, duplicate, office-for-mac, microsoft-excel-2011

I have 2 rather long lists of companies (a developing main list and several other lists which need to be compared to the main) I need to find duplicates (but also fuzzy duplicates) - e.g. "A company" in main list and "A company LLC" in new list, then the entry in new list should be eliminated. I found the plugin fuzzy lookup but I'm working on a mac. I tried making a new list with left() and eliminating exact duplicated but the lengths of the names seem to be too different from each other. Every hint is much appreciated - thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with the advanced filtering option in excel 2011 on a mac.

- Highlight the items to be sorted
- Go to Data->Advanced Filter
  -Select either filter the list in place, or copy the data to a new location (I always copy to a new location, because, Excel.)
- If you have some filtering criteria, enter that in the criteria range box, otherwise leave blank to filter everything
- check "unique records only"
- press OK.

Good luck.